# How to call exception after timeout socket connect Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have socket connection:

```
# Create a TCP/IP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    # Bind the socket to the address given on the command line
    sock.connect((host, port))
```

So, how to set timeout parameter and call exception when timeout comes?

```
login = login.encode()
        sock.sendall(login)
        sock.recv(buf).decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the socket documentation:

```
socket.settimeout(value)
```

"*Set a **timeout** on blocking socket operations. The value argument can be a nonnegative floating point number expressing seconds, or None. If a non-zero value is given, subsequent socket operations will raise a timeout exception if the timeout period value has elapsed before the operation has completed. If zero is given, the socket is put in non-blocking mode. If None is given, the socket is put in blocking mode.*

So you could specify it with:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(3) # 3 Seconds timeout.
```

That way a **socket.timeout** is thrown when the connection takes more than 3 seconds and you could handle the exception catching a socket.timeout in a try-catch block.